# Node js, put request with couchdb

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest, put

I am trying to send a `PUT` request from `JavaScript`. I am having trouble sending the value from `javascript` to `node js`, it is giving me the edit: `error is Unexpected token: o at Object.parse()`. on this line `var message = JSON.parse(req.responseText);` Maybe I should have mentioned I am using bodyParser.

```
       request.open("PUT", "myurl", true);
       request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       request.send(JSON.stringify({message: "from javascript"}));
```

from `node js` I want to send that value to `couchDB`but I am not sure how to get the `message` value passed from `javascript`

```
router.put('/fillMessage', function(req, res){
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     //...
    var message = req.body;

    var newData = {_id: data._id, _rev: data._rev, message: "JS value goes here"};
    //...

});
```

Now I am debugging the node js `req` variable and there seems to be no json value being passed into it. There is no `responseText`, or `body` attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often `Unexpected token: o at Object.parse()` means that whatever you're trying to parse is not a JSON-encoded string. It is likely already an object, for example `JSON.parse({ two : 2 })` gives that same error.

JSON.parse tries to turn the input into a string, then parse it as JSON, so in

```
var foo = { two : 2 };
JSON.parse(foo); // throws, equivalent to JSON.parse("[object Object]")
```

When working with `JSON.parse` it's a good idea to check that `req.responseText` is a string first, and wrap `JSON.parse` in a try/catch block.

Comment: Thanks I have edited my code but still, the req variable does not have the javascript values being passed into it. There is no .body or .responseText attributes. Am I doing something wrong in the javaScript?